# How to DRY in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dry

How could I make this shorter and extendable:

```
  def overview
    puts "All As:"
    for f in @a
      puts f
    end
    puts "\n"  

    puts "All Bs:"
    for f in @b
      puts f
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for f in @a
  puts f
end
```

can we written

```
puts @a.join("\n")
```

In the general case, when you want to do something with several arrays you can put the arrays into an array and then use `each` e.g.

```
[@a, @b].each do |list|
  list.each { |value| puts value }
end
```

and once you get onto doing something more complicated than just printing out the values it makes sense to use the extract method refactoring on the operation you're performing e.g.

```
[@a, @b].each do |list|
  do_something_with list
end
```

Finally, if you need to keep descriptive labels ("All As" etc.) you can use a hash:

```
{'As' => @a, 'Bs' => @b}.each_pair do |label, values|
    puts "All #{label}"
    puts values.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: is there a way to have at least a small label/tag for @a and @b printed? question answered in your second part! thanks!

Comment: Hongli's comment was posted before I expanded the answer with multiple suggestions. For clarity, he is referring to the use of `join` which will build a new string containing all the values.

Comment: 'puts values.join("\n")' could be replaced by 'puts values'.

Comment: `[@a, @b].each do |list|
  list.each { |value| puts value }
end` could be simplified in one line of code like that `[@a, @b].flatten.each { |value| puts value }`.

Answer (score 4):

```
def print_all(header, ary)
  puts header
  for f in ary
    puts f
  end
end

def overview
  print_all("All As:", @a)
  puts
  print_all("All Bs:", @b)
end
```

Comment: 'for f in ary; puts f; end'  is unnecessary. Just 'puts ary' will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like that :

```
def overview
    [@a, @b].each do |e|
        puts e.join("\n")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guess...

```
def overview
  puts "All As:"
  puts_a(@a)
  puts "\n"

  puts "All Bs:"
  puts_a(@b)
end

def puts_a(strs)
  for str in strs
    puts str
  end
end
```